# Passing information between components in Angular 10 (console.log works, but interpolation doesn't)

Tags: string-interpolation, angular10

I'm having trouble transferring information for interpolation to an uncle/aunt component.
My components are organized like this:

```
src -> app -> layout
           -> modules -> search
```

My search component can print the information out fine with interpolation, but when it sends the information over to layout, the information arrives fine but cannot be printed with interpolation.

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
     name:string = "default";
     layout:LayoutComponent = new LayoutComponent();
     
     public changeName(input:string)
     {
        this.name = input; //prints out fine with interpolation
        this.layout.printJSON(input); //calls the function in question
     }
 }
```

This code, with the help of {{ name }}, prints out the value that it is given without difficulty. However, when it calls printJSON(), the function prints with console.log, but interpolation fails {{searchResults}}.

```
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit{
    searchResults: string = "hello";

    public printJSON(name:string){
        if(name){
           console.log(name); //prints out the correct string
           this.searchResults = name; //doesn't print out with interpolation
        }
     }
 }
```

Edit: here is the HTML where I am calling changeName().

```
<div class="content" role="main">
<div *ngIf="!layout.mySearch">
    <span><h2 color="black">Find an organization</h2></span>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <form class="example"  [formGroup]="profileForm" (submit)='changeName(myInput.value); mySearch=true; myImage = false'><!--square brackets one way binding-->
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" formControlName='firstName' #myInput>
        <button type='submit'><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form> 
    <span><h4 color="black"><div>Advanced Search</div></h4></span>
</div>
```

So here, the string passed in to this search button is saved by #myInput and is passed to changeName() with a submit of the search button. The last line is {{name}}, which prints whatever I put into the search bar successfully.

Comment: can you share your HTML template?
 check this  default value prints with interpolation `searchResults: string = "hello";`?
in HTML => `{{ searchResults}}`

Comment: I don't think there is an error with interpolation. if you get value in function and `console.log()` it should work. you can check [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/yurzui/1hk7knwq/)

Comment: I updated it to include the HTML that calls changeName(). It prints out hello fine as an initial value, and when I put the same code in printJSON into ngOnInit(), it works fine. My boss agrees that the interpolation should work, which is why I wonder if it's because I'm not calling the uncle/aunt component correctly.

Comment: I don't think it's anything in the layout.component.html file because when I comment out all the code besides {{ searchResults }} and put the printJSON() code in the ngOnInit(), it seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with helper function in `ngOninit` as you said in the comment

> code in the ngOnInit(), it seems to work fine

with these changes, you can achieve interpolation. also here is a working example [Interpolation Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zgeyta?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  searchResults: string = "hello";
  name:string  = "Ananymous";
  data_name:string;//helper property to hold data for better understanding
  
  ngOnInit() {
   this.name="Saad"//hard corded naem for example
        if(name){
           console.log(name); //prints out the correct string
           this.data_name = this.name; //you said your code works till here and prints data in ngOnInit()? now lets create another helper function.
        }
       this.interPolateData(this.data_name)//helper function 
     }
     
   interPolateData(name:string){
     this.searchResults = name //interpolation works now please check
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
The problem was I was sending information from a method in search to a method in layout, and the data wouldn't print via interpolation in layout. To fix this, I just returned the data back to the original search method and printed it out there via interpolation. Thanks everyone for the help!